# mapreduce programs using eclipse in CDH4

Tags: eclipse, mapreduce

I am very new to Java, eclipse and Hadoop things, so pardon my mistake if it my question seems too silly.

The question is:

I have 3 node CDH4 cluster of RHEL5 on cloud platform. CDH4 setup has been completed and now I want to write some sample mapreduce programs to learn about it.
Here is my understanding to how to do it:
To write Java mapreduce programs I will have to install Eclipse in my ***main*** server, right? Which version of eclipse should i go for.
And just installing eclipse will not be enough, I will have to do some setting changes so that it can use my CDH cluster, what are the things needed to do this?
and last but not least, could you guys please suggest some sites where i can get more info regarding same, remember i am just beginner in all these..:)

Thanks in advance...
pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Pankaj, you can always visit the [official page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html). Apart from this you might find these links helpful :

- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-use-eclipse-with-mapreduce-in-clouderas-quickstart-vm/
- http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-run-mapreduce-programs-using.html#.UgH8OWT08Vk

It is not mandatory to have Eclipse on the main server(main server=master machine???). Any of the last 3 versions of eclipse work perfectly fine. Don't know about earlier versions. You can either run your job through Eclipse directly or you can write your job in Eclipse and export it as a jar. You can then copy this jar to your JT machine and execute it there through the shell using **hadoop/jar** command. If you are running your job directly through the eclipse you need to tell it the location of your NameNode and JobTracker machines though these properties :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://NN_HOST:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "JT_HOST:9001");
```

(Change the hostnames and ports as per your configuration).

One quick suggestion though. You can always search for these kind of things before posting the question. A lot of info is available over the net and it is very easily accessible.

HTH